# Fancytree - Generate tree with php

Tags: php, file, directory, directory-structure, fancytree

I am using Fancytree, I want to generate a file/folder tree but excluding all folders that are not from the current user.

Example:

```
UPPERCASE = FOLDER
lowercase = file
```

I want to create a tree structure with the user "Peter"

[image: Tree image]

I have several problems:

1. I don't understand the `listFolders` function, I can't give it a parameter (like $ name_user) otherwise it doesn't work.
2. the lines >> `print_r ('TAKE THIS'. $ Dir);` << show what I want to take, but it is `foreach` which does not work
3. my code is duplicated because I can't create a function inside a function ...

Here is my code:

```php
    <?php
    $name_user = 'Peter'; // actualy not user :-( 
    print_r(listFolders());
    
    function listFolders($dir = __DIR__ . '/datausers') {
        $dh = scandir($dir);
        $name_user = "Peter";
        $return = [];
    
        if (strpos($dir, "/datausers/PERSONNAL") !== false){ // PERSONNAL found !
            if ($dir === __DIR__ . '/datausers/PERSONNAL') {  
                print_r('TAKE THIS' . $dir);
                echo '</br>';
    
                foreach ($dh as $item) {
                    if ($item != '.' && $item != '..') {
                        if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $item)) { // it's a folder
                            $return[] = array(
                                'title' => $item,
                                'folder' => true,
                                'expanded'=> true,
                                'children' => listFolders($dir . '/' . $item, $key)
                            );
                        } else { // it's a file
                            $return[] = [
                                'title' => $item,
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
            if (strpos($dir, "/datausers/PERSONNAL/" . $name_user) !== false){ // Peter found
                print_r('TAKE THIS' . $dir);
                echo '</br>';
    
                foreach ($dh as $item) {
                    if ($item != '.' && $item != '..') {
                        if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $item)) { // it's a folder
                            $return[] = array(
                                'title' => $item,
                                'folder' => true,
                                'expanded'=> true,
                                'children' => listFolders($dir . '/' . $item, $key)
                            );
                        } else { // it's a file
                            $return[] = [
                                'title' => $item,
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        else {
            print_r('TAKE THIS' . $dir);
            echo '</br>';
    
            foreach ($dh as $item) {
                if ($item != '.' && $item != '..') {
                    if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $item)) { // it's a folder
                        $return[] = array(
                            'title' => $item,
                            'folder' => true,
                            'expanded'=> true,
                            'children' => listFolders($dir . '/' . $item, $key)
                        );
                    } else { // it's a file
                        $return[] = [`enter code here`
                            'title' => $item,
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.
It's crazy I spent the day yesterday on this problem.
and today I finally find the solution. Thank you requinix for answering me.

I put here my solution (not perfect) but it works.

```
<?php
if(session_status() != 2) { session_start(); } else { header('Location: deco.php'); } // (2 = session active) if don't active session
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])) {header('Location: deco.php');} // redirection si pas de session ouverte
if (time() > $_SESSION['expire']) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: deco.php');
}
$e1 = isset($_POST['e1']) ? $_POST['e1'] : null;
$e2 = isset($_POST['e2']) ? $_POST['e2'] : null;
if (empty($e1) || empty($e2)) {
    $return_data['key1'] = 'error';
    echo json_encode($return_data);
    return;
}

if ($e1 == 'read'){
    $e2 = str_replace('<','',$e2); // just for prevent html injection
    $e2 = str_replace('?','',$e2); // just for prevent php injection
    $return_data['key1'] = 'read';
    $return_data['key2'] = $e2;
    echo json_encode($return_data);
    return;

    $e2 = str_replace('}','',$e2); 
    $e2 = str_replace('"','',$e2); 
    $e2 = explode(":", $e2);        // take only name node 
}

if ($e1 == 'tree'){ 
    if ($_SESSION['username'] !== $e2){ // verification right name user
        $return_data['key1'] = 'error';
        $return_data['key2'] = ' tree authentication problem';
        echo json_encode($return_data);
        return;
    }
    echo json_encode(listFolders($e2, __DIR__ . '/datausers')); // $e2 = name user
    return ;
}

function listFolders($path_user, $dir) {
    $dh = scandir($dir);
    $name_user = $path_user;
    $return_data = [];

    if (strpos($dir, "/datausers/PERSONNAL") !== false){ // PERSONNAL found !
        if ($dir === __DIR__ . '/datausers/PERSONNAL') {  
            foreach ($dh as $item) {
                if ($item != '.' && $item != '..') {
                    if ($item === $name_user){ // Take only a user
                        if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $item)) { // it's a folder
                            $return_data[] = array(
                                'title' => $item,
                                'folder' => true,
                                'expanded'=> true,
                                'children' => listFolders($name_user, $dir . '/' . $item, $key) 
                            );
                        } else { // it's a file
                            $return_data[] = [
                                'title' => $item,
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (strpos($dir, "/datausers/PERSONNAL/" . $name_user) !== false){ // Peter found
            foreach ($dh as $item) {
                if ($item != '.' && $item != '..') {
                    if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $item)) { // it's a folder
                        $return_data[] = array(
                            'title' => $item,
                            'folder' => true,
                            'expanded'=> true,
                            'children' => listFolders($name_user, $dir . '/' . $item, $key) 
                        );
                    } else { // it's a file
                        $return_data[] = [
                            'title' => $item,
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        foreach ($dh as $item) {
            if ($item != '.' && $item != '..') {
                if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $item)) { // it's a folder
                    $return_data[] = array(
                        'title' => $item,
                        'folder' => true,
                        'expanded'=> true,
                        'children' => listFolders($name_user, $dir . '/' . $item, $key)
                    );
                } else { // it's a file
                    $return_data[] = [
                        'title' => $item,
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $return_data;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise build a tree structure with a different directory level and a filter of the directories to be taken.
if it can help someone :)

Root
--Admin [here PHP script]
--Datauser [here tree structure to take]

```
$e2 = "name folder";
$path_array = explode('/', __DIR__); // put path to array
$path_shortcut_array = array_slice($path_array,0,(count($path_array)-1)); // rebuild array path without the last 
$path_base_string = implode("/", $path_shortcut_array); // rebuild with '/'

echo json_encode(listFolders($e2, $path_base_string . '/datausers')); // $e2 = name user

function listFolders($path_user, $dir) {
    $dh = scandir($dir);
    $name_user = $path_user;
    $return_data = [];

    if (strpos($dir, "/datausers/PERSONNAL") !== false){ // PERSONNAL found !
        $path_array = explode('/', __DIR__);
        $path_shortcut_array = array_slice($path_array,0,(count($path_array)-1));
        $path_base_string = implode("/", $path_shortcut_array);
        
        if ($dir === $path_base_string . '/datausers/PERSONNAL') {  
            foreach ($dh as $item) {
                if ($item != '.' && $item != '..') {
                    if ($item === $name_user){ // Take only a user
                        if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $item)) { // it's a folder
                            $return_data[] = array(
                                'title' => $item,
                                'folder' => true,
                                'expanded'=> true,
                                'children' => listFolders($name_user, $dir . '/' . $item, $key) 
                            );
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (strpos($dir, "/datausers/PERSONNAL/" . $name_user) !== false){ // user found
            foreach ($dh as $item) {
                if ($item != '.' && $item != '..') {
                    if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $item)) { // it's a folder
                        $return_data[] = array(
                            'title' => $item,
                            'folder' => true,
                            'expanded'=> true,
                            'children' => listFolders($name_user, $dir . '/' . $item, $key) 
                        );
                    } else { // it's a file
                        $return_data[] = [
                            'title' => $item,
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        foreach ($dh as $item) {
            if ($item != '.' && $item != '..') {
                if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $item)) { // it's a folder
                    $return_data[] = array(
                        'title' => $item,
                        'folder' => true,
                        'expanded'=> true,
                        'children' => listFolders($name_user, $dir . '/' . $item, $key)
                    );
                } else { // it's a file
                    $return_data[] = [
                        'title' => $item,
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $return_data;
}
```